# Kotlin define interface for enum class values method

Tags: class, kotlin, enums, interface

if I define an enum class, let's say:

```
enum class MyEnum { }
```

I can do the following as enum class all have a `values` method:

```
val values = MyEnum.values()
```

Now I want my enum to implement an interface and have access to the values() method:

```
enum class MyEnum : EnumInterface { }

interface EnumInterface {
    fun values() : Array<T>

    fun doStuff() {
        this.values()
    }

}
```

This doesn't compile and I'm sure how to type the values method. Is it possible to define such interface? Thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You were really close to correct answer. You need to define generic interface and you enum should extend it typed with enum's class like this:

```
enum class MyEnum : EnumInterface<MyEnum> {
    A,B,C;
    override fun valuesInternal() = MyEnum.values()
}

interface EnumInterface<T> {    
    fun valuesInternal():Array<T>

    fun doStuff() {
        this.valuesInternal()
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for replying! It does compile when MyEnum is empty, but unfortunately does not when adding cases

Comment: I would have loved to avoid the valuesInternal() implementation but it does the job, thanks! :)

Comment: @lorenzo to a pity you can't make values to be override method and that's why it won't work.