# Kotlin: common interface on Enum class with static method to map from String

Tags: kotlin, enums

Suppose I have many enum classes like the following:

```java
enum class Hero(val alias: String) {
    SUPERMAN("Clark Kent"),
    BATMAN("Bruce Wayne");

    companion object {
        fun fromAlias(value: String): Hero? = Hero.values().find { it.alias.equals(value, true) }
    }
}

enum class Villain(val alias: String) {
    TWO_FACE("Harvey Dent"),
    RIDDLER("Edward Nigma");

    companion object {
        fun fromAlias(value: String): Villain? = Villain.values().find { it.alias.equals(value, true) }
    }
}
```

I'd like to be able to create a generic interface to handle the `fromAlias` method in such a way that I can still call it using `Hero.fromAlias("Bruce Wayne")`. So my enum classes would be simplified to something like:

```java
enum class Hero(override val alias: String): AliasedEnum<Hero> {
    SUPERMAN("Clark Kent"),
    BATMAN("Bruce Wayne");
}

enum class Villain(override val alias: String): AliasedEnum<Villain> {
    TWO_FACE("Harvey Dent"),
    RIDDLER("Edward Nigma");
}
```

I attempted to incorporate the answer from [Kotlin define interface for enum class values method](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56126945/kotlin-define-interface-for-enum-class-values-method), but couldn't see a way to access the enum values() from the companion object in the interface. Is there a clean way to do what I am wanting?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You can quite easily do this by using the fact that `companion object` objects can extend other classes.

Pretty much any solution will require two different parts, since you need:

1. A common interface that provides any data required for the function, so it is available regardless of the actual implementation.
2. A way to attach the shared function to the `companion object` for `<Class>.function` access. This can either be an abstract class with the required implementation or a marker class with the implementation as an extension function.

In the end the "cleanest" solution would probably be this:

```
// Attaching point for the extension function which provides the answer
interface EnumCompanion<T : Enum<T>>

// Marker interface to provide the common data
interface WithAlias {
    val alias: String
}

inline fun <reified T> EnumCompanion<T>.fromAlias(
    value: String
): T? where T : Enum<T>, T : WithAlias {
    return enumValues<T>().find { it.alias == value }
}

// Define the enums and attach the helper to their companion object
enum class Hero(override val alias: String) : WithAlias {
    SUPERMAN("Clark Kent"),
    BATMAN("Bruce Wayne");

    companion object : EnumCompanion<Hero>
}

enum class Villain(override val alias: String) : WithAlias {
    TWO_FACE("Harvey Dent"),
    RIDDLER("Edward Nigma");

    companion object : EnumCompanion<Villain>
}

fun main() {
    println(Hero.fromAlias("Bruce Wayne"))
    println(Villain.fromAlias("Edward Nigma"))
}
```